# sigmoid_cross_entropy loss function from tensorflow for image segmentation

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm trying to understand what the `sigmoid_cross_entropy` loss function does with regards to image segmentation neural networks:

Here is the relevant Tensorflow source [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/600caf99897e82cd0db8665acca5e7630ec1a292/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py#L107):

```
zeros = array_ops.zeros_like(logits, dtype=logits.dtype)
cond = (logits >= zeros)
relu_logits = array_ops.where(cond, logits, zeros)
neg_abs_logits = array_ops.where(cond, -logits, logits)
return math_ops.add(
    relu_logits - logits * labels,
    math_ops.log1p(math_ops.exp(neg_abs_logits)), name=name)
```

My main question is why is there a `math_ops.add()` at the return? Is the add referring to the summation of the loss for every pixel in the image or is the summation doing something different? I'm not able to properly follow the dimensional changes to deduce what the summation is doing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` is used in multilabel classification.

The whole problem can be divided into binary cross-entropy loss for the class predictions that are independent(e.g. 1 is both even and prime). Finaly collect all prediction loss and average them.

Below is an example:

```
import tensorflow as tf


logits = tf.constant([[0, 1],
                      [1, 1],
                      [2, -4]], dtype=tf.float32)
y_true = tf.constant([[1, 1],
                      [1, 0],
                      [1, 0]], dtype=tf.float32)
# tensorflow api
loss = tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy(multi_class_labels=y_true,
                                       logits=logits)

# manul computing
probs = tf.nn.sigmoid(logits)
loss_t = tf.reduce_mean(y_true * (-tf.log(probs)) +
                        (1 - y_true) * (-tf.log(1 - probs)))

config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True  # pylint: disable=no-member
with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
    loss_ = loss.eval()
    loss_t_ = loss_t.eval()
    print('sigmoid_cross_entropy: {: .3f}\nmanual computing: {: .3f}'.format(
        loss_, loss_t_))
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#output: 
    sigmoid_cross_entropy:  0.463
    manual computing:  0.463
```

Comment: How is this reconciled with multi-class prediction? For instance, if I'm doing prediction for 3 classes, does this loss reflect the loss for a single class? If so wouldn't there be 3 loss values, and then what happens to these 3 losses? Do they get averaged or summed?

Comment: If you have a multi-class problem, then you should use `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` instead.

Comment: 1.  `binary_crossentropy` only expect 1-D probs and labels, I'm not sure   2. multilabel prediction is independent, YOLOv3 use this loss to caculate `Class Prediction` [cf.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.02767.pdf) @Jonathan

Comment: Consider this network: https://www.kaggle.com/keegil/keras-u-net-starter-lb-0-277?scriptVersionId=2164855 and if I were to change num_classes to 4 in the `outputs` layer, this network still runs and uses `binary_crossentropy` quite well to do multi-label prediction. Hence, each class must be independently handling the error for that class. But the network produces one single loss value. That's what I'm getting at, does that make sense?

Comment: additional and correction: `binary_crossentropy` can be used in `Multiclass, multilabel classification` as well.  you mean `K.mean(K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred), axis=-1)` normalize twice, but  for `K.binary_crossentropy`, `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` is under the hood, `tf.**nn**.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` is different from `tf.**losses**.sigmoid_cross_entropy`, the former return A Tensor of the same shape as logits with the componentwise logistic losses.

Comment: Just caught that, thanks. I actually asked another question along the same lines: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52034983/how-is-total-loss-calculated-over-multiple-classes-in-keras perhaps you have insight to this.

Answer (score 3):

In this case `math_ops.add()` corresponds to [tf.add(x,y)](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/add) which is just adding two Tensors of the same size together, the dimension of the result is the same as the arguments.

When you use `sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` for a segmentation task you should do something like this:

```
loss = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=labels, logits=predictions)
```

Where `labels` is a flattened Tensor of the labels for each pixel, and `logits` is the flattened Tensor of predictions for each pixel.

It returns `loss`, a Tensor containing the individual loss for each pixel. Then, you can use

```
loss_mean = tf.reduce_mean(loss)
```

to average the losses of all individual pixels to get the final loss.

Comment: Please see the comment on bugkiller's answer.