# how to use tensorflow tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am doing some semantic segmentation problem and need to define loss function.

Does any one know how to use tensorflow "tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy"?

It is said in the documentation that the first input of the function is 
onehot_labels, so do we need to first transfer the pixel-wise class label into one hot encode format and input one hot encode into this function?

Or we can directly input the pixel class label like tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy in this post [sigmoid_cross_entropy loss function from tensorflow for image segmentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52046971/sigmoid-cross-entropy-loss-function-from-tensorflow-for-image-segmentation)?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I basically solved my problem, please see the following code of demonstration.

```
# each element is a class label for vectors (eg,[2,1,3]) in logits1
indices = [[1, 0],[1, 0]]
# each 1d vector eg [2,1,3] is a prediction vector for 3 classes 0,1,2;
# i.e., class 0 is predicted to be 2 and class 1 is predicted to be 1
# softmax will map this to corresponding probabilities
logits1 = np.array([  [[2.0,1.,3.],[2.,1,3]],   [[1.0,2.,3.],[2.,1,3]]   ])
print(logits1)
depth = 3

# first go to one hot encode format
# depth is nb of classes
encode = tf.one_hot(indices, depth)
# dim of encode must be equal to dim of logits
test = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels = encode, logits = logits1)
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init_op.run()
    print(sess.run(encode))
    print(sess.run(test))
```

What thss function really does is the following:

```
(-np.log(np.exp(1)/(np.exp(1)+np.exp(2)+np.exp(3)))-np.log(np.exp(2)/(np.exp(2)+np.exp(1)+np.exp(3))))/4 +\
(-np.log(np.exp(2)/(np.exp(1)+np.exp(2)+np.exp(3)))-np.log(np.exp(2)/(np.exp(2)+np.exp(1)+np.exp(3))))/4
```