# Sum of two losses in Keras (Perceptual and MSE)

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, loss-function

I want to add perceptual loss in my objective function to the MSE loss. I wrote below code for this:

```py
def custom_objective(y_true, y_pred):

   tosub = K.constant([103.939, 116.779, 123.68])
   y1 = vgg_model(y_pred * 255. - tosub)
   y2 = vgg_model(y_true * 255. - tosub)
   loss2 = K.mean(K.square(y2 - y1), axis=-1)
   loss1 = K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
   loss = loss1 + loss2

return loss
```

the problem is that shape of `loss1` is something like `(BatchSize, 224, 224)`, but the shape of `loss2` is `(BatchSize, 7, 7)`, so it gives me error about incompatible shapes which is right. I want to know how could I add this two properly? should I unravel first? and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loss function should always return a scalar (per sample in the batch or over the whole batch), since we want to minimize it (i.e. you can't minimize a vector, unless you define what you mean by "minimizing a vector"). Therefore, one simple way to reduce this to a scalar is to take the average across all the axes, except the batch axis which is averaged over internally:

```
loss2 = K.mean(K.square(y2 - y1), axis=[1,2,3])
loss1 = K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=[1,2,3])
loss = loss1 + loss2
```

**Update:** Let me clarify that it is OK if the loss function returns a vector or even an n-D array (actually the loss function above returns a vector of length `batch_size`), but keep in mind that at the end [Keras takes the average of returned values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52210610/2099607) and that's the real value of loss (which would be minimized).

Comment: yeah, thank you. Just I want to know keras itself return non- scaler value for mean squared error when the output is image, so it automatically get sum or mean over them?

Comment: @Panda That's right, as you mentioned internally it would average the values, even if the loss function returns a vector. Actually, I have written a [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52210610/2099607) about this, if you are interested to know more.